# Is a number a multiple of the other in Java

Tags: java, modulus

I wrote a simple program to check if 2 numbers are multiples of each other.

My issue is that the program outputs that they are multiples no matter what integers are input.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class twoIntegerMultiples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1, num2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("%nEnter second number: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();

        boolean multiple = isMultiple(num1,num2);

        if(multiple = true){
            System.out.printf("%n%d and %d are multiples of each other", num1, num2);
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("%n%d and %d are not multiples of each other", num1, num2);
        }


    }

    public static boolean isMultiple(int num1, int num2){

        int remainder = num1 % num2;
        boolean multiple;

        if (remainder != 0){
            multiple = false;
        }
        else{
            multiple = true;
        }

        return multiple;
    }

}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `if(multiple = true)` assigns `true` to `multiple`, and then checks if that new value is `true` (which it always is). Just write `if(multiple)`.

Comment: `==` for comparison.  `=` for assignment.

Answer (score 4):

There is bug in your code.

```
 if(multiple = true) // assigning  true to multiple
```

Here your are assigning `true` to `multiple`. Bu you should compare `true` with `multiple`.

Replace above line with

```
if(multiple == true) // Checking if multiple is true or checking equality
```

In java `=` is assignment operator and `==` is equal to operator.

**Another way**

You can directly write `multiple` in your `if` condition:

```
if(multiple)
```

As `if` accepts `boolean` datatype we can directly use `multiple` in `if`.

Comment: It is worth noting that a comparison returns a new boolean, which is either `true` or `false`, e.g. either `multiple` or `!multiple`. Normally one would simply write `if(multiple)`.

Comment: @Gendarme Thanks for suggestion. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong operator to check is `multiple`  is true. Currently you have:

```
if(multiple = true) //....
```

With this, you are forcefully assigning `true` to `multiple`, and it will always be true. You need to have:

```
if(multiple == true) //... '==' to check for equality.
```

Also, your `isMultiple()` function can be simplified, using boolean logic, to this:

```
public static boolean isMultiple(int num1, int num2){

    int remainder = num1 % num2;
    boolean multiple = true;

    if (remainder != 0){
        multiple = false;
    }
    return multiple;
}
```

In fact, you could simplify this EVEN more like this:

```
public static boolean isMultiple(int num1, int num2){
    return !(num1 % num2 != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if(multiple = true)
```

That sets multiple to true then checks
     If(multiple) 
after it has been set true therefore it will always return true.

Use == for comparisons of primitive data types like int, char, boolean etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a complete program with the mistakes fixed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1, num2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("%nEnter second number: ");
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        boolean multiple = isMultiple(num1, num2);
        if (multiple) {
            System.out.printf("%n%d and %d are multiples of each other", num1, num2);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%n%d and %d are not multiples of each other", num1, num2);
        }
    }
    private static boolean isMultiple(int num1, int num2) {
        int remainder = num1 % num2;
        boolean multiple;
        if (remainder != 0) {
            multiple = false;
        } else {
            multiple = true;
        }
        return multiple;
    }
}
```

Test

```
Enter first number: 350

Enter second number: 7

350 and 7 are multiples of each other
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the improper use of the assignment operator, you must also observe that for integers a and b, then in general (a % b) != (b % a), e.g. 2%72 = 2 != 0 = 72%2.

Comment: I think your code needs to take this into consideration.